# Is it secure to only validate form by JavaScript if the form is submmited via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

There is a way to detect if a request is submit via AJAX

```
    if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"])=="xmlhttprequest"){ 
         // ajax 
    }else{ 
         // not ajax
    };
```

If the form can only be submitted via `AJAX`, so it must has been validated by `JavaScript` before submitting, does that mean I don't need to validate it again in `PHP`?

Comment: No, it is NEVER secure to rely only on client side validation.

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] its not reliable method ....

Comment: So there is no way to skip validating the forms in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should validate form data php side too. Because you should never give a client a chance in exploiting your app. As we know, client side javascript is all visible for a client and that code can be manipulated as client wants.

Answer (score 1):

**Always** validate on both sides. Front side data is easy to manipulate, the backend however is unreachable. Never trust clients, ever.

Answer (score 0):

All headers which server is receiving from client side can be easily forged.
So, you should **never** trust anything that comes from client side, and should **always** validate on server side.